# Problem in opening a file which was saved using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV-python for creating video file using images.

When I run the code then no errors are shown and after 11 or 14 seconds the code executes.

But when I try to open the video file which was saved by the code. It raised an error in opening the file.

In VLC it's showing only a blank screen and in windows media player it's showing this:-
[image]

And the size of the video is 8.00 Kb always.
Here is the code:-

```
import cv2
import os
from os.path import isfile, join

def imgToVid(imgPath, vidSavePath, fps):
    '''This function will convert images to video'''
    frames = []
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(imgPath) if isfile(join(imgPath, f)) ]
    for i in range(len(files)):
        fileName = imgPath + files[i]
        '''reading images'''
        img = cv2.imread(fileName)

        # height, width, layers = img.shape
        # size = (width, height)

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(vidSavePath,  cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), fps, (1280, 720))  
    for j in range(len(frames)):
        out.write(frames[j])

    out.release()

imgPath = 'C:/Users/yash/Desktop/videocap/'
vidSavePath = 'C:/Users/yash/Desktop/testvideo.mp4'
fps = 14
imgToVid(imgPath, vidSavePath, fps)
```

Comment: please show us the text of the error message you receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append `img` in `frames`

```
frames = []
files = [f for f in os.listdir(imgPath) if isfile(join(imgPath, f)) ]
for i in range(len(files)):
    fileName = imgPath + files[i]
    '''reading images'''
    img = cv2.imread(fileName)
    frames.append(img)
```

Comment: It worked buddy. Thanks! (By the way "frames.append(img)"

Comment: yeah it was a typo :D